# Formatting JSON data in R

Tags: json, r, rstudio

I'm really new to working with JSON data, so I had a question about formatting.

Here's [the link to the data I was trying to work with](http://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashptshotlog?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&Period=0&PlayerID=202322&Season=2014-15&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=)

I was using JSONlite and did this:

```
shot<-"http://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashptshotlog?DateFrom=&DateTo=&
GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&
Outcome=&Period=0&PlayerID=202322&Season=2014-15&SeasonSegment=&
SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision="
```

I then did fromJSON:

```
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(shot), collapse=""))
```

This gives me the data in a list. My issue (although for all I know I messed up working towards this) is trying to create a data frame out of this info. I was able to make a data frame with code I read under similar questions on the site, but it is all of the data in just one column. Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, first thing to do when you get a JSON, you look at the structure.

```
str(json_data)
```

Doing so will reveal that your data has a very simple structure: is is a dataframe with rows, a line of headers, wrapped in some metadata about what each column means. Using the `$` will allow you to address those specific components. In other words, your specific json is already a data frame structure, all you gotta to is take it out of json

```
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(shot), collapse=""))
str(json_data)
mydf <- data.frame(json_data$resultSets$rowSet)
colnames(mydf) <- unlist(json_data$resultSets$headers)
```

You ought to get something like this:

```
head(mydf)

     GAME_ID                  MATCHUP LOCATION W FINAL_MARGIN SHOT_NUMBER PERIOD
1 0021401215 APR 14, 2015 - WAS @ IND        A L           -4           1      1
2 0021401215 APR 14, 2015 - WAS @ IND        A L           -4           2      1
3 0021401215 APR 14, 2015 - WAS @ IND        A L           -4           3      1
4 0021401215 APR 14, 2015 - WAS @ IND        A L           -4           4      1
5 0021401215 APR 14, 2015 - WAS @ IND        A L           -4           5      1
6 0021401215 APR 14, 2015 - WAS @ IND        A L           -4           6      1
  GAME_CLOCK SHOT_CLOCK DRIBBLES TOUCH_TIME SHOT_DIST PTS_TYPE SHOT_RESULT
1      10:33        7.7        0          1        25        3      missed
2       8:41         14       10        9.6      10.7        2        made
3       6:42       14.9       11        9.7      18.2        2      missed
4       5:16         19        3        3.5       4.2        2        made
5       4:45       19.8        3        3.7       3.3        2      missed
6       3:08       13.5       10        9.7        18        2      missed
  CLOSEST_DEFENDER CLOSEST_DEFENDER_PLAYER_ID CLOSE_DEF_DIST FGM PTS
1     Hill, George                     201588            4.3   0   0
2     Hill, George                     201588            5.7   1   2
3     Hill, George                     201588              3   0   0
4        Miles, CJ                     101139              4   1   2
5    Hill, Solomon                     203524              3   0   0
6     Hill, George                     201588            4.5   0   0
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick answer. Only issue I have with this is that the new data frame treats what should be each column as a row. So under the Game_ID column I have the first row output from every column with their own row. Did you do anything else to the data?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not clear on what you mean. Perhaps you mean to reformat the data? If so, look up `melt` and `dcast` in the `reshape2` library.

Comment: my bad on explaining that. Basically all of the data (besides the headers) are transposed. I'd use the transpose function, but that would in turn mess up the headers

Comment: so row 1 lists all of the Game_ID's, row 2 lists all of the Matchups, etc

Comment: Sorry, cannot replicate the problem. Make sure you are using the jsonlite package?